# Does iTunes sync Volume Adjustment and other per song settings?

Tags: itunes, data-synchronization

Does iTunes sync per song settings like Volume Adjustment, EQ, and Start-Stop times?

Comment: iTunes Sync to my iPod Shuffle: 1) Start-Stop times: YES, 2) Volume Adjustment: Don't know, 3) EQ: NO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start and stop times do sync, as well as volume adjustments.

EQ settings sync as well. However, they only work under the following conditions:

- You used a preset in iTunes (not custom EQ settings); and
- You have EQ disabled on the phone.

As backwards as that second one sounds, if you EQ enabled on the phone, it uses that EQ setting and overrides the per-song EQ settings. If you have EQ disabled on the phone, it uses the per-song EQ settings.